# How to get form values in browser to watir webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I have installed my application and it is running on following URL

http://localhost:3000

Above URL will the load form with some fields, Then I will the fill the data in the required field and then submit form. My div element will displayed at the bottom of the page. Picture will be displayed inside the iframe with in the div element.

User will the above URL and then submit form. After submitting the form, Picture should be downloaded into their local machine.

Right I am calling the following line after form submission, how can I get the existing page into the browser object and download screenshot?

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
b.div(:id => "phone_shell").screenshot("/home/user/Documents/preview.png")
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the [`Browser::html`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Browser#html-instance_method) or maybe the [`Browser::text`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Browser#text-instance_method)?

Comment: @Lakshmi you can get the screen html as a string when you write `b.html`.

Comment: @Lakshmi screenshot method is available for browser object not for the element object, you are calling screenshot method for element object.

Comment: @RAJ we can do it. Refer : https://github.com/ansoni/watir-extensions-element-screenshot

Comment: @Lakshmi Did you look at the answer below? Or not? I have updated the answer. You can do that but you need to `require 'watir/extensions/element/screenshot'` but I have given the answer which doesn't require this. Can you please look at the answer given below?

Comment: @Lakshmi Okay, that gem which you mentioned is to take the screenshot of the particular element, but that too works perfectly for me. What problem you have there? I have written this code for me `b.div(id: 'loginBox').screenshot('D:/Fixed/preview.png')` It perfectly works, before you write, just install this gem `watir-extensions-element-screenshot` and require this line `require 'watir/extensions/element/screenshot'

Comment: @Lakshmi You don't have to use watir-webdriver now, it's upgraded to WATIR, simply install `gem install watir`, it will allow you to code via Ruby selenium binding. New watir is wrapper around Ruby selenium-binding.

Answer (score 2):

I found few problems in your code

`screenshot` method is not available for element object, it's available for browser object and also you need to call the method save to save the file in the destination folder. So write the following code, it would work.

Code to get the html of the page

```
b.html
```

Code to take the screenshot

```
b.screenshot.save("/home/user/Documents/preview.png")
```

Now this will save the image in the destination folder.